# Assign a range to an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to create a function that will convert a range into an array.

So I want to define `function rangeToArray(myrng as Range)`, pass a **single-column** range such as `Range("A1:A100")` to the parameter `myrng`, and have the function return an equivalent **one-dimensional** array.

I didn't even know how to begin but tried the Answer and could only get a *two*-dimensional array in return.  I also wasn't sure how to make the function's return type be an array. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the range directly into the array.

```
Sub arr
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr() = Range("A10:A100")
End Sub
```

Or if you really need both steps:

```
Sub arr
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A10:A100")
    arr() = rng
End Sub
```

Edit for proof:

[image]